# Composition of mappings not working as expected

Tags: function-construction, code-request

I have two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and I define a third one $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ as the composition $$h(x,y) = g(f(x,y))$$
 I'm trying to get this function into `Mathematica` as a composition because I still want the functions $f,g$ and I don't want to have to manually update $h$ when I change $f$ or $g$.

So here is what I'm currently doing :

```
1. Define f[x_, y_] := {E^x + y, Sin[2 x]}
2. Define g[x_, y_] := {2 x + Cos[y], E^(x + y)}
3. Try the obvious definition of h[x_, y_] := g[f[x, y]].
```

This doesn't seem to work. I'll just get things like `h[0, 0]` returning `g[{1, 0}]`. I could write $h$ using  the projection of $f$ onto the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Projection function but this seems needlessly cumbersome and adds conjugate statements everywhere. Can anybody point out a better direction for defining $h$ as a composition?

Also I have tried the `Mathematica` function `Composition` and it behaved the same way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your functions take two arguments as input. Yet they return one argument as output. So the output of f cannot serve as the input of g and vice versa. You can't compose the functions with until the outputs of one function can serve as the input for the other function. Reduce your arguments in `f`, `g` by placing them in a list.

This appears to work:

```
f[{x_, y_}] := {E^x + y, Sin[2 x]}
g[{x_, y_}] := {2 x + Cos[y], E^(x + y)}
h[{x_, y_}] := g[f[{x, y}]]
```

**Example**

```
g[f[{2, 3}]]
f[g[{2, 3}]]
```

[image: compositions]

Answer (score 7):

When `f` and `g` have been defined this way :

```
f[x_, y_] := {E^x + y, Sin[2 x]}
g[x_, y_] := {2 x + Cos[y], E^(x + y)}
```

the problem is that `g` and `h` being two-argument functions,  then `g` is called as one-argument (i.e. a list returned by `f`) function `h[x_, y_] := g[f[x, y]]`. Instead of redefining `f` and `g` you can try another definitions of `h` as a composition of `f` and `g`, e.g. `h1` using [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html?q=Sequence&lang=en) (and `Apply`) or `h2` using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html?q=Apply&lang=en) only :

```
h1[x_, y_] := g[ Sequence @@ f[x, y]]
h2[x_, y_] := g @@ f[x, y]
```

they both work well :

```
h1[x, y] == h2[x,y]
h1[x, y]
```

> ```
> True
> ```
>
> [image]

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party, but here's a function I wrote to compose arbitrary $\mathbb{R}^M \to \mathbb{R}^P$ functions with $\mathbb{R}^P \to \mathbb{R}^N$ functions:

```
Clear[multiDimComposition]
multiDimComposition[flst__]:=
 With[{fcns = Reverse@List[flst]},
  Fold[#2[ Sequence @@ #1 ]&, First[fcns][##], Rest[fcns]]&
 ]
```

Here's a few examples

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_, y_] := Sin[2 \[Pi] x y^2]
g[s_] := {s, s^3}
multiDimComposition[f, g][s]
(*  Sin[2 Pi s^7] *)
```

The reason I created it was to specify arbitrary paths in multidimensional functions, as follows

```
GraphicsRow[{Show[
   DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], 
   ParametricPlot[g[s], {s, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black]
   ], Plot[multiDimComposition[f, g][s], {s, -1, 1}]}]
```

[image]

Here's the transformation to spherical coordinates:

```
Clear[f, g]
f[x_, y_, z_] := Exp[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]
g[r_, t_, f_] := {r Sin[t] Cos[f], r Sin[t] Sin[f], r Cos[t]}
multiDimComposition[f, g][Rho, Theta, Phi] // 
   Simplify[#, Rho > 0] &
(* E^Rho *)
```

There is a flaw, though, as written the functions must have downvalues, or it won't work:

```
multiDimComposition[f, {s, s^2}][s]
(* f[s] *)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition) directly:

```
f[x_, y_] := {E^x + y, Sin[2 x]}
g[x_, y_] := {2 x + Cos[y], E^(x + y)}

h = Apply[g] @* f;
```

Then:

```
h[x, y]
h[2, 3]
```

> {2 (E^x + y) + Cos[Sin[2 x]], E^(E^x + y + Sin[2 x])}
>
> {2 (3 + E^2) + Cos[Sin[4]], E^(3 + E^2 + Sin[4])}

in agreement with the other answers.