# Composing two functions in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Composition of mappings not working as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13420/composition-of-mappings-not-working-as-expected)

I am new to *Mathematica* and I am having trouble defining a certain composition of functions.

Let `m1` and `m2` be maps such that $m_1: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $m_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ where $\mathbb{R}$ is the real line

```
m1[eta_, zeta_] = {eta^3, zeta^3} 
m2[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2

m3[eta_, zeta_]  = Composition[m2, m1][eta, zeta]
```

On evaluating the last line, I get the output

```
(* m2[{eta^3, zeta^3}] *)
```

But the anwer to this should be `m3[eta,zeta]=eta^6 + zeta^6`

How can I do this?

Comment: `m3[eta_, zeta_] = m2 @@ m1[eta, zeta]` see documentation about `Apply`

Comment: `Composition` is only meaningful for single-argument functions.  Make your functions take a single list-argument instead of several scalar arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If your `m1` function outputs a list of 2 values, your `m2` function should take that as input. Makes sense, right?

```
m1[eta_, zeta_] = {eta^3, zeta^3}
m2[{x_, y_}] = x^2 + y^2
```

Otherwise, make it return a `Sequence`

```
m1[eta_, zeta_] = Sequence[eta^3, zeta^3]
m2[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2
```

Now

```
m3[eta_, zeta_] = Composition[m2, m1][eta, zeta]

(*eta^6 + zeta^6*)
```

Comment: but then why shouldn't m1 take a list of 2 values, too?

Comment: @RolfMertig I agree, both getting a list may be a cleaner design

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is clearer? :

```
m1[{eta_,zeta_}]={eta^3,zeta^3};
m2[{x_,y_}]=x^2+y^2;
m3[{eta_,zeta_}]=Composition[m2,m1][{eta,zeta}]
```