# About composition of functions (I don't want to use a vector variable function)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, vector-calculus

```
f2[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^3;
g[t_] := {t^2, 3*t+1}
```

$g$ returns a list, but $f_2$ is a two variable function.
So, we cannot compose these functions:

```
f2[g[1]]
```

---

```
f1[v_] := v[[1]]^2 + v[[2]]^3
g[t_] := {t^2, 3*t+1}
```

We can compose these functions like the following:

```
f1[g[1]]
```

But I don't want to use a vector variable function like $f_1$.

---

Any good idea?

Comment: Would defining `f1[{x_,y_}]:=x^2+y^3` be what you want?

Comment: @JohnDoty Thank you very much. f1[g[1]] worked.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(15749)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15749/121).  Also (merely) related: [(6588)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/121), [(13420)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13420/121), [(26686)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26686/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
ClearAll[f2, g]

f2[{x_, y_}] := f2[x, y]
f2[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^3;
g[t_] := {t^2, 3*t + 1}

f2[g[1]]
```

> ```
> 65
> ```

Comment: Mr. Wizard, Thank you very much. f2[{x_, y_}] := f2[x, y] is very nice idea.

Comment: @tchappyha Happy to help.  See also the Q&A's linked in my comment to your Question for more and related examples.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've already got several good answers, but I thought I would mention `Apply`.

```
f2[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^3
g[t_] := {t^2, 3 t + 1}
f2@@g[1]
```

> 65

The head of the result of evaluating `g[1]` is `List`, and `Apply` replaces this with `f2`. Essentially, `List[1, 4]` --> `f2[1, 4]`.

Answer (score 1):

And along the lines of @MassDefect,

```
f = {#1^2 + #2^3} &
g = {#1^2, 3 #1 + 1} &
f @@ g[1]
```

Pure functions can be a solution too. Result is {65} as expected.